# How to use multiple middleware user role inside controller on Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie in Laravel and trying on middleware user role. I created 2 middlewares, 'superadmin' and 'admin' as below.

For superadmin

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->permission != '1')
    {
        return new Response(view('unauthorized')->withRole('Super Admin'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

For admin

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->permission != '2')
    {
        return new Response(view('unauthorized')->withRole('Admin'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I put to my target contoller via __contruct method. There's no problem if controller need only single middleware. But problem on controller that require both middleware (superadmin &admin assessible). I try as below but not work.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
    $this->middleware('superadmin');
}
```

Appreciated for all advise, thanks.

Comment: Check my blog post on this https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/02/12/set-up-role-based-access-control-in-laravel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a single middleware and have a dynamic parameter to validate the permission. Create a new middleware to determine user permission. In that middleware, you can do this,

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission = 0)
 {
        //allowed only to specified permission
        if (($request->user() && $request->user()->permission == $permission) || $permission === 0) {
            return $next($request);
        }

     return new Response(view('unauthorized')->withRole('Admin'));
 }
```

and when you apply the middleware you can do it like this,

```
public function __construct()
{
    //allow only admin
    $this->middleware('permission:1');
    //allow only super admin
    $this->middleware('permission:2');
   //allow both admin and supper admin
    $this->middleware('permission');
}
```

For more information refer to this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-parameters). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use middleware in route in web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission1','permission2']], function () {
    //
});
```